# How do I export into pdf in phantomjs with this link.

Tags: pdf, phantomjs, kibana-4, rasterize

I have read about phantomjs and rasterizejs as well. But my link is this:

```
http://localhost:5601/#/dashboard/External?_g=(time:(from:'2014-12-31T16:00:00.000Z',mode:absolute,to:'2015-01-01T16:00:00.000Z'))&_a=(filters:!(),panels:!((col:10,id:'Count-of-Source-IPs-(External)',row:1,size_x:3,size_y:3,type:visualization),(col:4,id:'Protocols-(External)',row:4,size_x:3,size_y:2,type:visualization),(col:7,id:'Top-5-Source-IPs-with-Protocols-and-Source-Port-(External)',row:4,size_x:6,size_y:6,type:visualization),(col:1,id:'Top-5-Source-IPs-(External)',row:4,size_x:3,size_y:2,type:visualization),(col:1,id:'Top-5-Countries-with-Protocols-(External)',row:1,size_x:6,size_y:3,type:visualization),(col:1,id:'Geographical-of-External-(Source)',row:6,size_x:6,size_y:4,type:visualization),(col:7,id:'Action-(External)',row:1,size_x:3,size_y:3,type:visualization)),query:(query_string:(analyze_wildcard:!t,query:'*')),title:External)
```

How do I make it such that it works with this command:

```
phantom.js rasterize.js "http://localhost:5601/#/dashboard/External?_g=(time:(from:'2014-12-31T16:00:00.000Z',mode:absolute,to:'2015-01-01T16:00:00.000Z'))&_a=(filters:!(),panels:!((col:10,id:'Count-of-Source-IPs-(External)',row:1,size_x:3,size_y:3,type:visualization),(col:4,id:'Protocols-(External)',row:4,size_x:3,size_y:2,type:visualization),(col:7,id:'Top-5-Source-IPs-with-Protocols-and-Source-Port-(External)',row:4,size_x:6,size_y:6,type:visualization),(col:1,id:'Top-5-Source-IPs-(External)',row:4,size_x:3,size_y:2,type:visualization),(col:1,id:'Top-5-Countries-with-Protocols-(External)',row:1,size_x:6,size_y:3,type:visualization),(col:1,id:'Geographical-of-External-(Source)',row:6,size_x:6,size_y:4,type:visualization),(col:7,id:'Action-(External)',row:1,size_x:3,size_y:3,type:visualization)),query:(query_string:(analyze_wildcard:!t,query:'*')),title:External)" external.pdf
```

I have been getting syntax error because of that.

Comment: What do you hard-coding it in the script? By creating a .sh file and putting the url in? I think I will stilll get syntax error because of the brackets and many other symbols in the url given

Comment: how do i do that? sorry im not good at phantom.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that the command is too long for your terminal and some of it is cut off.

You can either directly put it into the script or read it from stdin. For that you need to edit rasterize.js.

First you need to reduce the `x` in all `system.args[x]` where `x` is above 1 by 1. If you've done that, then you can call the script as

```
phantom.js rasterize.js external.pdf
```

or

```
cat file.url | phantom.js rasterize.js external.pdf
```

in the second case.

#### Put URL into script

Change

```
address = system.args[1];
```

to

```
address = "http://localhost....";
```

#### Read from pipe

You can put your long URL into some file and pass that file to stdin of the PhantomJS script.

Change

```
address = system.args[1];
```

to

```
address = system.stdin.read();
```